# Let $A, B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices. Show that $AB = O$ but $BA \ne O$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A, B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices. Show that $AB = O$ but $BA \ne O$. Explain this result geometrically.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1& 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$ $$B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$$

I kinda get it algebraically that $AB = O$ and $BA$ is not $O$ however, i don't understand what do you mean by explain this result geometrically.

I see in book saying matrix $A: x \to x$ to represent function but

still don't get it because prof never explain to us and we need to read textbook and solve

our own.

please help me

Comment: You need to edit your post to indicate what $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: What is $O$ here?

Comment: Do you know what the range and kernel of a matrix are?

Comment: Consider orthogonality, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just use words here: you can add the diagrams.

The matrix $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &1\\2&2\end{array}\right]$ sends the vector $X=\left[\begin{array}{c}p\\q\end{array}\right]$ to the vector $AX = \left[\begin{array}{c}p+q\\2p+2q\end{array}\right]$. This means that $A$ sends all points in the plane to the line $y=2x$ and all points on the line $y=-x$ to the origin.

The matrix $B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}-1 &3\\1&-3\end{array}\right]$ sends the vector $X=\left[\begin{array}{c}p\\q\end{array}\right]$ to the vector $BX = \left[\begin{array}{c}-p+3q\\p-3q\end{array}\right]$. This means that $B$ sends all points in the plane to the line $y=-x$ and all points on the line $y=\frac13x$ to the origin.

The matrix $AB$ does the $B$ transformation then the $A$ transformation, which sends all points in the plane to the line $y=-x$ then to the origin. In other words, $AB$ is the zero transformation.

The matrix $BA$ does the $A$ transformation then the $B$ transformation, which sends all points in the plane to the line $y=2x$ then to the line $y=-x$. In other words, $BA$ is *not* the zero transformation.

Again, all this can be illustrated by diagrams.